Why is my lambda only moving .zip files from one S3 bucket to another?
I have my code here that I am using to move my files in my S3 bucket. I am using a trigger in my lambda to move files upon "all objects created".
import boto3
import urllib

TARGET_BUCKET = 'final bucket name'

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get incoming bucket and key
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    source_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])

    # Copy object to different bucket
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': source_bucket,
        'Key': source_key
    }
    s3_resource.Bucket(TARGET_BUCKET).Object(source_key).copy(copy_source)
    
    # Delete the source object
    #s3_resource.Bucket(source_bucket).Object(source_key).delete()

I test it by creating a new folder in the my source bucket, running the lambda, then checking the destination bucket. When I create a folder called "test_1" it doesn't move to the destination. When I change the name to "test_1.zip" then it moves the folder. I am not sure why.
I did notice the "package type" section in the lambda description has "zip" but I can't seem to remove that. Is that the issue? I'm using python 3.10

Because there are no actual folders in an s3 buckets therefore the directory you create is not object to be copied or whatever.

"I did notice the "package type" section in the lambda description has "zip" but I can't seem to remove that. Is that the issue?" That is completely unrelated to the issue. That is just saying that you upload the Lambda function's source code as a .zip file.

So you've tried one folder, and one file, and from that you've determined that it only supports .zip files? Have you tested a .txt file or any other file format?

@ParmanM.Alizadeh should just make his comment the answer, because that is issue.  S3 is made up of buckets and objects.  "Folders" are actually prefixes for objects.  Nothing happens when you create a prefix in the UI until you also then create an object with that prefix.

thank you for your help, leave an answer as a proper response instead of a comment here then i will choose it as best answer thanks @parman m alizadeh

In Amazon S3, there are no actual folders or directories as you might find in a traditional file system. What appears to be a folder structure in S3 is actually a logical organization based on object key prefixes. For more details on the organization of objects in s3, see this.
